# Which classes are scanned during the Swagger auto-configuration process?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springfox

In the Swagger docs I read that the `@SwaggerDefinition` annotation can be placed in any of the classes that are scanned during the Swagger auto-configuration process.

I put the annotation in my controller class inside the controller package, and I set this package as a `base-package` using the `context:component scan` tag in my `dispatcher-servlet.xml`. However, the Swagger UI page still shows the default title, contact email, etc. which means it's not picking up my `@SwaggerDefinition`.

How do I resolve this problem? Any pointers would be appreciated. Kinda lost atm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [springfox](http://springfox.io) the equivalent of @SwaggerDefinition is using the api in the [Docket](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/blob/master/springfox-spring-web/src/main/java/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/Docket.java) to customize the service description. The @SwaggerDefinition annotation is not supported in springfox.